# Result Difference between int and float in Generic Function

Tags: c++

Compile and run my code; compare the result if you are using integers or floats with fractional values. Why is there a difference?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>

T find(T array[], T len, T num){    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        if (array[i] == num) 
             return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main () {  
    int array1[5] = { 4, 7, 3, 5, 6 }, num1;
    float array2[5] ={121.2, 111.5, 300.1, 500.1, 600.1 }, num2;

    cout << "Enter an int:" << " " ;
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Enter a float:" << " " ;
    cin >> num2;        

    int x = find<int>(array1,5,num1);
    float y= find<float>(array2,5,num2); 

    cout << "The index for the int is:" << "  " << x << endl;         
    cout << "The index for the float is:" << "  " << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find the difference between the two results when using ints and when using floats.

Comment: Why len is T? Should be size_t...
And the return type is an index, so it should also be different.. ptrdiff_t, I would say, or int if you do not like ptrdiff_t

Comment: What do you mean "what is the difference"?

Comment: Also, what difference would you expect? The template function, once you adjust types for length and index type, should work on any data type for which operator== is defined...

Comment: @dema80 You should [not compare floats with `==`](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).

Comment: This is the question that I'm trying to answer. Would there be any type of difference in the result if searching for int or searching for float using this method.

Comment: @user2364471 the question is still very vague.. what do you mean by "any type of difference"?

Comment: @dema80 It's actually a question from a book. I'm trying to find an answer for it. I do agree with you, it's very very vague.

Comment: @user2364471 pick another book then... It is a very low quality one, if it has such errors about types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you must not compare floats with `==` due to the internal representation of floating point numbers. If you are using the result from an expression, it can mathematically be correct to find the number in the array, but due to the limitations in the floating point representation the `==` would not find it.

Consider the following code:

```
template<class T>
int find(T array[], size_t len, T num){    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        cerr << std::setprecision(7) << "Compare: " << array[i] << ", " << num;
        if (array[i] == num) {
             cerr << " => equal" << endl;
             return i;
        } else {
             cerr << " =>not equal" << endl;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main () {  
    float array2[2] ={500.1, 1.0 }, num2;

    float a = 500.1 / 2;
    int i = find<float>(array2, 2, 2*a); 

    a = 1.0 / 0.3333;
    i = find<float>(array2, 2,  a * 0.3333); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Compare: 500.1, 500.1 => equal
Compare: 500.1, 0.9999999 =>not equal
Compare: 1, 0.9999999 =>not equal
```

So, even though `1.0 / 0.3333 * 0.3333` is `1.0` mathematically, it is not when using floating point arithmetics - it is `0.99999` instead. Therefore `==` does not treat the numbers as equal in the last comparison.

To solve this, compare the difference of the two numbers to a small `epsilon` value. `float.h` explicitly defines the constant `FLT_EPSILON` for this:

```
if (fabs(array[i] - num) < FLT_EPSILON) { ...
```

Comment: So should I compare floats with?

Comment: But in my case it still finds the number. Try compiling and running my code, and search for any floating point number in the array. You would get back the index of that number.

Comment: @user2364471 Yes, it depends on the actual number and how it was calculated. See my code, `1.0 / 0.3333 * 0.3333` is mathematically 1.0, and cerr also prints it as such, but the `==` treats them as different

Comment: @user2364471 Read Andreas link.. http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm it is a good primer!

Comment: @user2364471 Also, I think this is as good as an answer you can get... how are the two different? The "find" function you posted works for integers, it may not work for floats (due to rounding issues)